# QuickOSM not returning all buildings visible in OpenStreetMap

Tags: quickosm

When querying `buildings` in `canvas extend` the results don't contain all the buildings visible in OpenStreetMap. Why not?

[osm.org link](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=seattle#map=15/47.6097/-122.3384)

Here is the query:

```
[out:xml] [timeout:25];
(
    node["roof:shape"="dome"]( {{bbox}});
    node["roof:shape"="flat"]( {{bbox}});
    node["roof:shape"="gabled"]( {{bbox}});
    node["roof:shape"="gambrel"]( {{bbox}});
    node["roof:shape"="half-hipped"]( {{bbox}});
    node["roof:shape"="hipped"]( {{bbox}});
    node["roof:shape"="mansard"]( {{bbox}});
    node["roof:shape"="onion"]( {{bbox}});
    node["roof:shape"="pyramidal"]( {{bbox}});
    node["roof:shape"="round"]( {{bbox}});
    node["roof:shape"="saltbox"]( {{bbox}});
    node["roof:shape"="skillion"]( {{bbox}});
    node["type"="building"]( {{bbox}});
    node["building"="apartments"]( {{bbox}});
    node["building"="house"]( {{bbox}});
    node["building"="garage"]( {{bbox}});
    node["building"="industrial"]( {{bbox}});
    node["building"="entrance"]( {{bbox}});
    node["amenity"="loading_dock"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="dome"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="flat"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="gabled"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="gambrel"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="half-hipped"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="hipped"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="mansard"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="onion"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="pyramidal"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="round"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="saltbox"]( {{bbox}});
    way["roof:shape"="skillion"]( {{bbox}});
    way["type"="building"]( {{bbox}});
    way["building"="apartments"]( {{bbox}});
    way["building"="house"]( {{bbox}});
    way["building"="garage"]( {{bbox}});
    way["building"="industrial"]( {{bbox}});
    way["building"="entrance"]( {{bbox}});
    way["amenity"="loading_dock"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="dome"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="flat"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="gabled"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="gambrel"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="half-hipped"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="hipped"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="mansard"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="onion"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="pyramidal"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="round"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="saltbox"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["roof:shape"="skillion"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["type"="building"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["building"="apartments"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["building"="house"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["building"="garage"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["building"="industrial"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["building"="entrance"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["amenity"="loading_dock"]( {{bbox}});
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the distinction between them may not be perfect. I've also seen buildings on the OSM but treated as closed lines in OSM data. Whether it is a simple bug or a data problem, it seems that you have no choice but to check the pbf yourself.

Comment: Without more information, it's difficult to anwser you. Maybe share your query, a permalink to the area on osm.org, the logs of QuickOSM (in the QGIS comic strip bubble), the content of other layers etc. This would help.

Comment: Thanks @etrimaille N00b so not sure where to find all that. I edited the post with the data you're looking for.

Comment: The link to the building you are looking for : https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/216321012